# Handling / sanitising user input with unicode/UTF8 in an application that doesn't handle it

Tags: c++, linux, unicode, utf-8

I have a console application in linux that doesn't handle unicode/UTF8 and I have no plans of implementing it, as there is just no need -- other than this problem.

User's are entering commands into the the prompt containing no ascii characters and this is causing grief as far as mysterious problems with data and also in text config files that should only contain ascii characters.

What is the best way to go about dealing with this problem?
Is there a not too complicated way of converting the unicode strings back to ascii or removing any removing any characters that can't be printed using the visible part of ascii character set?

Unicode just seems like a complete nightmare too me.

Comment: So you don't want to handle UTF-8... except for when people use UTF-8 with your application and you want to handle that. It seems to me that the best way to handle this is to *handle UTF-8*. If your users want to use UTF-8, let them.

Comment: Unicode is a blessing for programmers, and it should take you one or two days to understand it. http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UTF-8 and many single-byte character sets are ASCII-compatible, values between 0-127 represent the proper ASCII characters.
(In case of UTF-8, each byte of character that has a multi-byte sequence is outside this range.) Filtering out the rest solves your issue.

You should definitely change your attitude and support UTF-8 though.

Comment: I noticed in a string the other day that instead of spaces there was a char -96 instead. If I simply remove this (not replace it with space) the string is kind of ruined. This was a config file, so I simply did a search and replace.

Comment: The byte -96 alone is not allowed in an UTF-8 text, it has to be at least the second byte of a multi-byte character. Are you sure it was UTF-8?

Comment: Not 100% but the source of the text the was inserted, was an application using UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: If you want to know what's actually stored, and have access to the Visual Studio IDE, read some file into a buffer, and look at the MEMORY WINDOW in the debugger to see what's actually being stored. Throwing out every-other char can be as simple as a modulo operation when reading from a buffer to a buffer. Unicode is a nasty and frustrating problem, I agree. Kind of appalling it's also Notepad's default setting.

Comment: Or simply use the linux `hexdump <filename>` command to print out the bytes of a file.

Answer (score 0):

If ASCII is required then test for and reject any char value outside 0-127 as invalid input. I don't hold with the traditional [robustness principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle) in cases like this; code should [fail fast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast). Trying to massage ambiguous data will lead to [weird behaviour](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/04/17/2158334.aspx).

*Of course, much depends on the domain, but this is my default approach. It is easier to be strict first and relax conditions later than it is to be lax and try to apply restrictions afterwards that break previously working code/configurations.*